# Want to use a PNY GTX 1050Ti on a GA-H270 GAMING 3 but it doesn't work

Tags: motherboard, bios, gpu

I just built a PC for gaming i used the next parts for my build:

- [Intel Core i5-7500](https://ark.intel.com/products/97150/Intel-Core-i5-7600-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-4_10-GHz)
- [Gigabyte H270-GAMING 3](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-H270-Gaming-3-rev-10)
- [Kingston HX421C14FB2/8](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/HX421C14FB2_8.pdf) 8Gb 2133MHz RAM
- [PNY GTX 1050Ti](http://www.pny.com/geforce-gtx-1050-ti-4gb)
- Toshiba 1Tb 3.5
- 650W power supply with 80 plus bronze

The issue I have is that the PC works fine but if I install the graphic card it doesn't give me signal on my monitor and I don't know what could be the issue. I even updated the BIOS version from f4 to f7 and nothing works

Does anyone knows something about this issue or could help me fix this?

Comment: Did you check the cable connections? Does the fan of the card spin up? Did you make sure to connect your display cable to the card instead of the on board chip? Did you try to connect it to the on board chip to see whenever you're getting a signal there with the card installed?

Comment: "Did you check the cable connections?"
-yes, it does not havea 6 pin conector 

"Does the fan of the card spin up?"
-yes, it works fine

"Did you make sure to connect your display cable to the card instead of the on board chip?"
-yes, i used a hdmi cable to do all my work

"Did you try to connect it to the on board chip to see whenever you're getting a signal there with the card installed?"
-also yes but neither ports (mobo or gpu) worked,
i knew pc boot up correctly but didnt show up any signal

Comment: Also i dont know much about the bios but does this have to do with the reason i dont have video signal from my card
`Initial Display Output
Specifies the first initiation of the monitor display from the installed PCI Express graphics card or the onboard graphics.
IGFX Sets the onboard graphics as the first display.
PCIe 1 Slot Sets the graphics card on the PCIEX16 slot as the first display. (Default)
PCIe 2 Slot Sets the graphics card on the PCIEX4 slot as the first display. ` 
-from the mobo manual

Comment: Well what did you set that to? What slot did you use for the card?

Comment: @Seth i used the 1st PCI but im at home right now i will modifiy this setting in a momnent just to see if i can use the on board graphic while the gpu is intalled, maybe i can install the nvidia driver to make the gpu work. i will keep you updated about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp in the end the main problem was that the windows 10 wasnt recognizing the gpu.
i made a fresh install of windows 10 pro but didnt updated until this morning. 
and that fixed the whole problem 
the device administrator showed up the gpu and the nvidia installer had no problem while doing the update